# Angular - should I run production build before test or after test

Tags: angular, typescript

If I am building a Java app for production, I'd have the build setup to build the production artefacts and then run the tests against those artefacts.

I've just joined an Angular project and noticed that the build is setup something like this:

`ng test && ng lint && ng build --prod`

..so its running test and lint before the actual build. Is the reason one might choose to do this an attempt to fail faster because the test build is quicker? Is this standard practice in Angular apps?

Comment: Yes, it's definitely quicker than building and testing afterwards. At our company we have switched lint and test stages because then it fails even faster and there's imho no point in excecuting tests, when there are lint errors anyways

Comment: Yep...Standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Angular tests run against the source files, the build produces a set of minified js files for deployment. They are independent processes.

The series of commands you have is effectively saying:

```
if (source files passes tests && source files pass linting rules) {
  produce files for deployment
}
```

An Angular build isn't a particularly speedy process, so it's definitely better to fail fast if tests or linting fails. You're not running tests against outdated files - if that's the thrust of your question.